# How to take a site collection backup without Active directory and permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, backup, restore

I need to move our site collections from one server to another which have different AD and Domain, Please suggest any idea for better migration?

Comment: Hi . is the destination server  at diff farm ?

Comment: Ya Different farm @Qassas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different domain is not represented a big issue , where you should use the corresponding service accounts on the destination farm.

**Steps :**

- First of all, you should make sure that the SharePoint Build number of destination environment must be matched with the build number of the source environment, to make sure that check.

  - [Find the latest Cumulative Update / Farm Patch Level that has been installed in a SharePoint Farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-the-latest-cu-farm-patch-level-that-already-installed-in-your-sharepoint-farm/)
  - [This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/05/this-content-database-has-a-schema-version-which-is-not-supported-in-this-farm/)
- Take a backup of site collection from the old web application.

> ```
> Backup-SPSite -Identity http://siteURL -Path "C:\\MoveSiteCollection.bak"
> ```

- Create a new web application .
- Restore backup in the new web application.

> Restore-SPSite -Identity http://url -Path
>   "C:\MoveSiteCollection.bak"

**If you ensure that the content database have only this site collection you can use database-upgrade method as the following :**

- In source farm, Take a backup of the content database via SQl management Studio.
- In destination farm , Create A web application , Site collection.
- In destination farm , Dismount the the web application content database , via this command

`Dismount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentdBName>"`

- In destination , via SQL Management Studio , Restore the content database.
- In destination , Mount it to the created web application,

`Mount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentDb>" -DatabaseServer "<DbServer>" -WebApplication http://SiteName`

- In destination farm, Change Site collection administrator  to avoid the access permission issue. by going to site Setting > Site Collection Administrator > Set the site admin account in Dev.

For more details check [Restore / Migrate a SharePoint Web Application to another farm from SQL Database Backup](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/07/17/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Thank you so much,I will do, How can we  migrate the Mysite page in SharePoint 2013?@Qassas

Comment: Dear @SuriyaadevanBalu sorry for delay reply , it's the same method of content database upgrade method , but because you have a different domain you may face some issues so check this good article that describes the detail steps to do this http://www.widriksson.com/sharepoint-my-sites-migration-to-new-domain/

Comment: Sure , please invite me at new room